# long variable name when infile pipe delimited file into sas

Tags: sas, csv

I have a pipe delimited file when variable name is 40 bytes long. Is there an option in sas to specify the length?

Currently, SAS wouldn't read this file with lrecl= [a large enough number] dsd dlm='09'x.

Comment: Is your variable name long, or the values in the variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SAS variable names cannot be over 32 characters long.  You can allow SAS to make a decision about the variable names (shortening automatically) but retain the long variable name as a label, which is often the simplest procedure.  It shouldn't prevent it from loading, though.

However, more concerning is the fact that you say it is a pipe delimited file, but `dlm='09'x`, which is tab delimited.  Is this just a typo/word choice issue or are you doing this incorrectly?

Comment: Thanks Joe. It is a typo. I tried dlm='|', but not working either. The other thing I could think of is first couple of variable is long. Shall I specify the lengths using length or informat option?

Comment: One follow up question, Joe. How can I specify the length of variable name I want to keep. Say, I want keep 10 bytes for length of all variables.

Comment: You can't really control the variable _name_ length.  Your only real option is to import it by hand using a data step instead of proc import, then specify the names (you could write a program to do so, if you wanted, using macro variables).

Comment: Joe, for some reaason when I use SAS import wizard and check off this data has a label row. And it works. But it does have variable name on the first row.